# I am not able to execute the command which worked till yesterday

Tags: bash

I am not able to execute this command

```
/test/filename_*; do $(wc -l "$file" | cut -d' ' -f1) -eq 1  && m $file ; done
```

It worked till yesterday, somehow this is not working now.

Comment: what error you are observing?

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: Apparently something has change in the `/test` directory, do you still have `filenames_*` files?

Comment: that is probably because you have no files in the directory test with name filename_*

Comment: Also `wc -l < "$file"` and `shopt -s nullglob` would make your life a bit easier.

Comment: @AityaKutcharlapati : A lone `do` is indeed not legal, since `do` is a keyword (reserved word) for bash. You will get the same error if you just enter the `do` command on the bash command line.

Comment: whatever `m` is

Comment: This definitely never worked as shown here.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/595219

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you didn't have this command instead:

```
for file in /test/filename_*; do [ "$(wc -l "$file" | cut -d' ' -f1)" -eq 1 ] && rm "$file" ; done
```

Comment: missing a `test`

Comment: What do you mean @Jetchisel ?

Comment: *do [ $(...) -eq 1 ] && ...*

Comment: Ah ok sorry about that !

Comment: Thank you , when i used this command.. it is giving me -sh: m: command not found

Comment: Yes sorry I focused on the first error I saw (for file in /test/filename_*) as you said your command worked before, I thought you might have just missed the first part of your command.
Are you sure your command worked before as you put it ? And what command do you want to execute on your files when the test statement is true ? Was m a command alias or a typo error for another command ?

Comment: it should be `rm` for deleting files, see linked duplicates